# DirectX11 texture coordinates and vertices

Tags: c++, textures, directx-11, vertices

I am new to StackOverflow.

I am studying DirectX11 from the book Beginning Directx11 and I am a complete beginner but I do have knowledge of C++. I have come across texture coordinates and how they are used but I don't understand the snippet of code that is used to specify the vertices. Below is the code:

```
// the structure used to store the vertices
struct VertexPos
{
    XMFLOAT3 pos;
    XMFLOAT2 tex0;
};

// some code before reaching this point
...
VertexPos vertices[] =
{
    { XMFLOAT3(  1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f ), XMFLOAT2( 1.0f, 1.0f ) },
    { XMFLOAT3(  1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f ), XMFLOAT2( 1.0f, 0.0f ) },
    { XMFLOAT3( -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f ), XMFLOAT2( 0.0f, 0.0f ) },

    { XMFLOAT3( -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f ), XMFLOAT2( 0.0f, 0.0f ) },
    { XMFLOAT3( -1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f ), XMFLOAT2( 0.0f, 1.0f ) },
    { XMFLOAT3(  1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f ), XMFLOAT2( 1.0f, 1.0f ) },
};
...

// shader file
Texture2D colorMap_ : register( t0 );
SamplerState colorSampler_ : register( s0 );


struct VS_Input
{
    float4 pos  : POSITION;
    float2 tex0 : TEXCOORD0;
};

struct PS_Input
{
    float4 pos  : SV_POSITION;
    float2 tex0 : TEXCOORD0;
};


PS_Input VS_Main( VS_Input vertex )
{
    PS_Input vsOut = ( PS_Input )0;
    vsOut.pos = vertex.pos;
    vsOut.tex0 = vertex.tex0;

    return vsOut;
}
```

I don't understand why there are 6 positions specified. If it is to make a rectangle, is it not possible to specify 4 values and make a rectangle from two triangles? This loads a texture image and displays it, I would like to know how the vertices work (if possible with a drawing specifying the position of each vertex).

Comment: Please explain the difference you see between "specify 4 values and make a rectangle from two triangles" and "use four different coordinates (using two of them twice), in two groups (each with three different), for two triangles". The latter is what the quoted code does, isn't it?

Comment: i'm not sure what the code does with the 6 positions..and how the positions are meant to be used with the texture mapping, i don't understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say this example uses real triangles (each triangle 3 vertices together 6), if you want 4 vertices and two triangles you can use Triangle Strip https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_strip

Comment: actually, it uses Triangle List in the code..what i need to know is how the vertices are used with the texture being mapped..

Comment: The first 3 vertices are a triangle, and the second 3 verts are a triangle.  A Triangle list is a list of whole triangles.

Comment: i drew the first three and saw a left-angled triangle, now i understand the code better, thanks guys